# Perl Regex Replacement

Tags: regex, perl, replace, yaml, str-replace

I'm pretty new to Perl and have the following issue: I'm trying to replace a version number in a `.yml` file with a different value. This is what my regex looks like:

```
version:\s*([^\s]+)
```

It works so far, but it does not do what I like it to do.

Here the code that I currently have, and the Perl statement to replace the value in the `.yml` file.

file content(./test.yml):

```
app:
  version: 1.2
  name: abc
```

code:

```
$search = "version:\s*([^\s]+)";
$replace = '1.3';
perl -pie 's/$search/$replace/m' ./test.yml;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error/output you're getting now?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, however in the file it keeps showing "version: 1.2"

Comment: This seems to work:
$search = qr/(version:\s*)([^\s]+)/mp;
$replace = '"${1}1.3"'; Thanks :)

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder: Look-behinds cannot have variable length. That is, you can't have `\s*` inside `(?<=...)`.

Comment: What kind of code is that? I hope it's not meant to be a Perl script?

Comment: @zdim: It appears to be a shell script that calls a one-line perl script.

Comment: @SimonShine  What shell supports that syntax?

Comment: None that I know of. This code is not the actual code used. Coffeehouse Coder, please copy and paste the actual code that you're using.

Comment: Note that your data file is broken. `app` should be `app:`

Answer (score 5):

Why are you trying to re-implement a YAML parser in a one-liner?!

```
perl -MYAML=DumpFile,LoadFile -e'
   my $d = LoadFile($ARGV[0]);
   $d->{app}{version} = "1.3";
   DumpFile($ARGV[0], $d);
' test.yml
```

It seems unlikely that the new version should be hardcoded like that.

- Version comes from the outside.

  ```
  perl -MYAML=DumpFile,LoadFile -e'
     my $d = LoadFile($ARGV[0]);
     $d->{app}{version} = $ARGV[1];
     DumpFile($ARGV[0], $d);
  ' test.yml 1.3
  ```
- Version should be incremented.

  ```
  perl -MYAML=DumpFile,LoadFile -e'
     my $d = LoadFile($ARGV[0]);
     $d->{app}{version} =~ s/\.\K(.*)/ $1+1 /e;
     DumpFile($ARGV[0], $d);
  ' test.yml
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex seems fine, but your use of the `perl` command-line tool needs justifying:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=version:).*/ 1.3/' test.yml
```

Takeaways:

- Use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`.
- Use `perl -pi -e` and not `perl -pie`. (`-i` takes an optional argument.)

Depending on whether this is a one-time use regex or code that will be deployed, consider making the regex sensitive to the context of *(a)* *app* and *(b)* a version number lower than *1.3*; i.e. don't just bump any version number found in the file to *1.3*.

- Addressing *(a)*,

  ```
  perl -pi -e '$toplevel = $1 if /^(\S+)$/; s/(?<=version:).*/ 1.3/ if $toplevel eq "app"' test.yml
  ```

  This would push *app*'s *1.2* to *1.3* without touching *wat*'s in the following file:

  ```
  app
    version: 1.2
    name: abc

  wat
    version: 1.2
    name: wat
  ```
- Addressing *(b)*,

  ```
  perl -pi -e 's/(?<=version:)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/" " . ($1 < 1.3 ? 1.3 : $1)/e' test.yml
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this Simon. (a) makes the most sense for my use case. However, I'm not able to make it work. In the use case I'm looking at the app / wat level in your example are not on the top but rather within the structure (3rd level). I tried to remove the caret from the regex, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stefan: I can only answer questions that you ask. You're in irregular land here; you might be able to grab it by `^\s*app$` (but do note @ikegami's suggestion that this isn't valid YAML without an ending `:`, in which case you're building a simplistic YAML parser). Since the file is not so simple as you suggested, I'd recommend you go and use @ikegami's solution using the YAML package. You can install it with `cpan -i YAML`.